# Failed try tring to recreate the find method

Tags: javascript

Ok so i need to recreate the find method but i cant manage to suceed. I am trying to do this but everytime i run this on a array it simple returns me an error

```
  array.prototype.findDaShopee = function ( ok ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == ok[i]) {
            return this[i]
        })
    }

  }
```

but it's not working

I tried removing the 'ok' function, i tried everything, i dont want the answer just the explanation

i'm really tring to understand

Comment: The argument to the `find()` method is a function that should be called, not an array.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing the code that produces the error, and what the error in question actually is. Based solely on what you've provided here, there could be multiple different problems you're encountering.

Comment: you are using loose equality here, if you really want to do that read this comparison between `==` and `===`  [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 3):

The name of the class is `Array`, not `array`.

`ok` is not an array, it's a function that should be called on each element of the array. The method returns the first element where the function returns a truthy value.

You had an extra `)` in the code.

```js
Array.prototype.findDaShopee = function(ok) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (ok(this[i])) {
      return this[i]
    }
  }
}

const testArray = [1, 2, 10, 12];
console.log(testArray.findDaShopee(el => el % 5 == 0));
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning (or linking to something else that explains) that `Array.prototype.anythingHere = ...` is bad practice, because it makes the method enumerable in `for...in` loops (which are also bad practice)

Comment: This is obviously just a toy exercise, I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can you point me to a resource explaining why `for...in`-loops are considered bad practice? I haven't really used it yet (`Object.keys()` works fine _mostly_), but I don't understand why it may be bad practice.

Comment: @OskarGrosser See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261096/13561410) explains that `for...in`-loops may be misused as `for...of`-loops, where _the misuse_ is bad practice. But it doesn't consider `for...in`-loops themselves as bad practice (and neither do I). Thank you for the link!

Comment: There are dozens of other answers giving other reasons why it's not a good idea.

Comment: @OskarGrosser within the context of my comment, I was specifically referring to the use of `for...in` on arrays, but I also feel the semantics of `for...in` are confusing especially when considering poorly written libraries that improperly modify builtin prototypes like this question does. In contrast `Object.keys` is restricted to _own_ enumerable properties, so modifications to the prototype chain like this example won't modify what it returns.